# Найти элементы первого массива во втором

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно вывести список 'a', в котором покрашены элементы, которые есть в списке 'b'

```
from termcolor import colored
a = [['1', '2','  ', '3', '4'], ['5', '6', '  ','7', '8'], ['9', '10', 
'','11', '12'], ['13', '14', '15', '16']]

b = ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '28', '29', '31', '32', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50']

for i in range(len(a)): # вывод списка  'a'
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
       print(a[i][j], end=' ')
       print()
print(colored('Hello World!', 'green')) # пример покраски слова
```

Т.е если в списке 'b' есть 14, то покрасить 14 в списке 'a' и так далее
И в итоге вывести весь покрашенный список 'a'. А если в списке 'a' есть элемент к примеру '1' , а в списке 'b' его нет, оставить нетронутым

извиняюсь на табуляцию

[image: code]

Comment: обязательно числа должно быть в одном блоке ['14 16 15'] или их можно разбить ['14',  '16', '15']?

Comment: что за кошмар со списками? то однострочные числа, то строка с числами, сто список с числами - так и надо?

Comment: Поменял список 'b'

Comment: `if a[i][j] in b: ...`.

Comment: `for i in range(len(a)): # вывод списка  'a'
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        if a[i][j] in b:
            print(colored(a[i][j],'green'), end=' ')
    print()`   ----- а как вывести исходный список 'a' в котором эти элементы покрашены?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from termcolor import colored

a = [['1', '2', '  ', '3', '4'], ['5', '6', '  ', '7', '8'], ['9', '10',
                                                              '', '11', '12'], ['13', '14', '15', '16']]

b = ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26',
     '28', '29', '31', '32', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48',
     '49', '50']

a = sum(a, [])
for elem in a:
    if elem in b:
        print(colored(elem, 'green'))
    else:
        print(elem)
```

Что бы вывести только числа в колонку (по 4):

```
from termcolor import colored

a = [['1', '2', '  ', '3', '4'], ['5', '6', '  ', '7', '8'], ['9', '10',
                                                              '', '11', '12'], ['13', '14', '15', '16']]

b = ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26',
     '28', '29', '31', '32', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48',
     '49', '50']

a = sum(a, [])
result = []
for elem in a:
    if not str(elem).isdigit():
        continue
    if elem in b:
        result.append((colored(elem, 'green')))
    else:
        result.append(elem)

    if len(result) % 4 == 0:
        print(' '.join(result))
        result = []
```

Comment: как вывести в 4 колонки ? чтобы получилось 1 2 3 4 \n 5 6 7 8 \n 9 10 11 12 \n 13 14 15 16 ??

Comment: @user366600 должно получиться 1 2    3 \n
4 5 6   \n
7 8 9 10 \n
 11 12 13 так?

Comment: 1 2 3 4 первод строки 5 6 7 8 перевод строки и т.д

Comment: чтобы в каждом ряду получилось по 4 элемента

Comment: @user366600 у вас в списке пустые значения, их нужно тоже выводить?

Comment: нет, их из списка можно вообще убрать

Comment: @user366600 обновил ответ, если задача решена: поставьте галочку слева ответа под стрелочками.

Comment: спасибо! то, что нужно было